# Macbook Pro - Won't stay asleep

Tags: release-loki, macbook

Running 0.4 Loki.  If I put my MacBook to sleep it wakes a few seconds later.

I was advised to run the following command, but it is not helping.

sudo sh -c "echo XHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup"